# How come my program won't recognize another command?

Tags: c

I am currently writing a program's main function(the bare-bone function so far) so far I've only included the "end" command to end the program. Whenever anything else is typed that isn't a command, it will output an error message. However, now that I'm inputting more commands within the loop, it doesn't seem to be recognizing anything else. I'm writing a program that creates polynomials after prompting the user to enter coefficients and exponents.

The command is adc(add coefficient command) and after a space you're supposed to add an integer standing for the coefficient and another space with another integer standing for the exponent.

Example: adc 4 5
Output: 4x^5

```
int main(void){
    char buf[5]; //Creates string array
    unsigned int choice;
    printf("Command? "); // Prompts user for command
    fflush(stdout);
    gets(buf); //Scans the input

    while(strncmp(buf, "end", 3) != 0) //Loop that goes through each case, so long as the command isn't "end".
    {
        switch( choice ){
        //Where the other cases will inevitably go
            if((strcmp(buf,"adc %d %d"))== 0){
            }
        break;
            default:
              printf("I'm sorry, but that's not a command.\n"); //Prints error message if input is not recognized command
    fflush(stdout);
              break;
        }
        printf("Command? "); //Recycles user prompt
        fflush(stdout);
        gets(buf);
    }
    puts("End of Program."); //Message displayed when program ends
}
```

Comment: `gets(buf)` **Never use `gets`** says even the man page. And your buffer is too small for your expected input.

Comment: Where are your case statements for the switch?

Comment: Why is gets so frowned upon? It always seems to work. And for my switch I tried assigning choice to my scanf statement after my print but it kept going into an endless loop. I honestly dunno what to put into the switch anymore to have various cases because it can't be buf.

Comment: buf is length five, if you gets() the string "Veryugly stack disruping text", your stack is disrupted.

Comment: Why is gets so frowned upon?  You really should [read its man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gets).

Comment: I see, forgive me then, always nice to learn something new since I know practically nothing being a novice at this. Sorry for my mistakes

Comment: There's no need to apologise for your mistakes. Everybody makes mistakes all the time, particularly often in areas they're new to. I should have explained why you shouldn't use it instead of only quoting the man page (and yes, it's bolded in the man page). But, didn't your compiler tell you ``warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.``? Mine do even without warning level turned up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a format string like this: `strcmp(buf,"adc %d %d")` to test for a certain kind of input. Your `strcmp` will only signal string equality if the use inputs literally: `"adc %d %d"`, *not* `adc` followed by two integers.

You'll need to parse the input string manually, by tokenizing around whitespace characters, checking the first token with `strcmp` against e.g. `adc`, then parsing the numbers separately.

I don't notice any `case` statements in your `switch`. It looks like you can just remove the `switch`, since you're not using `choice` anywhere.

Also, don't use `gets`, use `fgets` instead.

Comment: I get an error stating that there are too few arguments for fgets.

Comment: you'll need some more arguments, it's not a drop-in replacement for `gets`: `fgets(buf, 5, stdin)`

Comment: Thanks, I should've just looked into it instead of demanding answers, sorry for that.